# removing the header from an unzipped CSV

Tags: regex, unix, csv, pipe

I'm using the following line in unix to unzip a .tar.gz file and push into all into a nice CSV file.

```
> gunzip -c foo.tar.gz > foo.csv
```

The problem is, there's a sort of header attached to the file, it looks like this:

```
path-to-csv-on-s3/foo.csv����������������������������000644 �000765 �000024 �00132244376 12501623550 027273� 0����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������ustar�00hills���������������������������staff���������������������������000000 �000000
```

I've tried using things like

```
gunzip -c s3-foo.tar.gz | sed "1 d" > foo.csv
```

to remove this first line, but it removes all the column names as well. Anyone know an easy way to fix this? Here's what the first few rows of data look like:

```
path-to-csv-on-s3/foo.csv000644 000765 000024 00132244376 12501623550 027273 0ustar00hillsstaff000000 000000 ������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������"","id","price", "lala", "hooha"
1, some-ID, 45, 'blah', 'yay',
4, some-ID, 32, 'lah', 'yay!'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this for your sed expression: `sed -e '1 s/^.*\(\"\".*\)/\1/'`.

That uses the substitute operator, which looks like `s/pattern-to-math/replacement/`.  I match the start of the line `^`, anything thereafter `.*`, followed by a capture group in `(...)`starting with `""` followed by anything, `.*`.  In the replacement part of the operator, I simply put in the capture group, `\1`.

I tested with `echo "path-to-csv-on-s3/foo.csv000644 000765 000024 00132244376 12501623550 027273 0ustar00hillsstaff000000 000000 \"\",\"id\",\"price\", \"lala\", \"hooha\"" | sed -e '1 s/^.*\(\"\".*\)/\1/'"","id","price", "lala", "hooha"` and it seemed to work nicely